# how to get rid of sensitive permission form even after removed the permission from manifest?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api, google-console-developer

Could anyone please try to help with me, I had removed the call log and out_going_process call permission from the manifest but google play app content it is still showing on it.

I have deactivated all the apk from beta,alpaha,production which has been included permission.Tried all the effort but nothing could help me, am suffocating for this last two days.

**I wanted to disappear the permission form from app content, Desperately need it**.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check in merge manifest of project, may be third party library use this permission.

Comment: no its fine only